# Controllers Communication in EmberJs

Tags: ember.js

Cheers, I am still learning EmberJS I am currently using the latest release RC8. I have this question

```
EmberApp.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(setupController: (controller) ->
# Set the IndexController's `title`
controller.set "title", "IndexRoute"
)

EmberApp.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
setupController: (controller, model) ->
# Set the IndexController's `title`
    controller.set "title", "ApplicationRoute"  
)
```

This is Index.js.handlebars

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h1>{{EmberApp.ApplicationController.title}}</h1>
```

The Controllers of both routes are empty, just the defenition

What I want to do is to print the following

## IndexRoute

## ApplicationRoute

How can I do this, in other words how can I access these attributes from of controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ApplicationRoute` is the topmost route, aka the route of your application, the `IndexRoute` is the first route in your application that comes after that, so basically if you have an `{{outlet}}` in your application template then this is where by default the index template will be rendered into.

Your example is showing the `IndexRoute` first then the `ApplicationRoute`, are you sure you want it the other way around?

Assuming you don't this is how it works:

### Application template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h4>{{controller.title}}</h4>
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

### Index template

will be fendered into the application template outlet

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <h4>{{controller.title}}</h4>
</script>
```

### Index route

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('title', 'IndexRoute');
  }
});
```

### Application route

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('title', 'ApplicationRoute');
  }
});
```

Here working example: http://jsbin.com/EpiqUMi/2/edit

### Update in response to your last comment

I didn't realize at first what you where after, but the method you where you looking for is called `this.controllerFor(...)` within a route you can use it to get whatever controller you need, see the following changed `IndexRoute` how this would look like:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    var otherTitle = this.controllerFor('application').get('title');
    controller.set('title', 'IndexRoute & ' + otherTitle);
  }
});
```

Here the updated example: http://jsbin.com/EpiqUMi/5/edit

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did it on computer exactly the same as you did in your working example. but the idea is I want to see if I can through the indexcontroller access the properties of applicationcontroller, if possible how can I render them in the indexcontroller.

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa, updated my answer, didn't realize first what you where after, I hope now it's clear

Comment: very impressive, I was looking for solutions to this problem now I have two solutions. I think this covers what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`needs`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#property_needs) property on your controller to specify a dependency on another controller.

```
EmberApp.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend
  needs: ['application']
```

#### index.js.handlebars

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h1>{{controllers.application.title}}</h1>
```

More info is in the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

#### Update

If you want to access the property from the route, the same technique can be used. The same path that would have been used from your template can be used on the controller. The template's default context *is* the controller.

```
EmberApp.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    @_super(arguments...)
    Ember.Logger.log(controller.get('controllers.application.title'))
```

Comment: this is correct, I was also about to propose using the `needs` API but it seams he wants to have access to it's controllers from a route

Comment: I think both answers are correct, I will read more about both solutions to see when to use what.

Comment: See updates in my answer. The result of `needs` can be used from the route, not just templates.